# Setup tools for android things1.0

Tags: raspberry-pi3, android-things

Where to find the setup tools for building an Android Things 1.0 image for Raspberry PI3.
Whith actuel Android Things console , using download tools give Android Things DP8 image.

Thank's for help

Comment: I did flash mine a few days ago and it fetched the latest version, even with an old version of the script. Are you getting the default image or a custom one?

Comment: Just reload Setup Utility (`android-things-setup-utility.zip`)  from "Tools" menu item of [Android Things Console](https://partner.android.com/things/console).

Comment: After reloading setup utility from Android Console all is OK!